# React Js only Load the first SVG

Tags: reactjs, svg

I want to load multiple SVG icons in a react component. but the component only load first SVG and others shown as a square or repeat first SVG icon
i load the SVG like this

```
import { ReactComponent as Back} from "./back.svg";
```

and use it as a component

I tried to load svg file and use img tag
but it has another issue to...

I didn't use any third-party package to load SVG
what is the best way to import SVG file in react js

Comment: Can you provide the full code for this component?

Comment: Are you using webpack, create-react-app or another thing?

Comment: Do your svg files have duplicate id values?

Answer (score 4):

I found what's the problem...
I had multiple SVG files that all of them had the same id in them...
when I load them together, the page had multiple tags with the same id and only show one image or an empty square

I changed each SVG tag's id and everything is OK now